# How to make smooth animation in css?

Tags: html, css, animation

I have used animation of translate(). The link to the code is here [Bouncy animation](http://codepen.io/Falcon43/pen/azYqxO)

But it starts off abruptly at the bottom. How to give it a smooth start. Also notice the animation distorts in between. How to remove such error?

The code is below:

```css
 body{background: #92348A;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
  
 .wrapper{ margin-left:370px;
   margin-top:195px;
   position:absolute;
   }
 p{ font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-weight:900;
 
  }
 .one{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:0.5em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #F00;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.2s infinite ;
  } 
 .two{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #9D1A76;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.38s infinite;} 
 .three{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #FF0080;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.3s infinite;} 
 .four{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #FF0;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.35s infinite;} 
 .five{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #0ECAF1;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.23s infinite;} 
 .six{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #0BF451;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.1s infinite;}
 .seven{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #645CF1;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.14s infinite;} 
  
 @-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    2%{ transform: translateY(120px);}
    50%{ transform:translateY(-90px);}
    100%{ transform:translateY(120px);}
    }
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="one">
         <p>W</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
         <p>E</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
         <p>L</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
         <p>C</p>
        </div>
        <div class="five">
         <p>O</p>
        </div>
        <div class="six">
         <p>M</p>
        </div>
         <div class="seven">
         <p>E</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Could I ask why you have included seperate classes for 1,2,3,4,5,6 and 7, when they're all declared in the same way (barr background color?)?

Comment: change 2% to 0% in @-webkit-keyframes bounce

Comment: @jbutler483 Yes , ua right. I ll give the divs an id for similar properties...and background color in it's class. Cool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@harcos answer is correct, but does not have a smooth start.
Add the `transform:translateY(-90px);`
to all the different animation classes for them to be rendered where the animation starts.

```css
body {
  background: #92348A;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 370px;
  margin-top: 195px;
  position: absolute;
}
p {
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.one {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #F00;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.2s infinite;
}
.two {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #9D1A76;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.38s infinite;
}
.three {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FF0080;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.3s infinite;
}
.four {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #FF0;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.35s infinite;
}
.five {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #0ECAF1;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.23s infinite;
}
.six {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #0BF451;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.1s infinite;
}
.seven {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #645CF1;
  text-align: center;
  transform:translateY(-90px);
  -webkit-animation: bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.1, .3, 1.9) 0.14s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    0%{ transform:translateY(-90px);}
    50%{ transform:translateY(120px);}
    100%{ transform:translateY(-90px);}
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="one">
      <p>W</p>
    </div>
    <div class="two">
      <p>E</p>
    </div>
    <div class="three">
      <p>L</p>
    </div>
    <div class="four">
      <p>C</p>
    </div>
    <div class="five">
      <p>O</p>
    </div>
    <div class="six">
      <p>M</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seven">
      <p>E</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks, you're right, I forgot there were 2 questions

Comment: @harcos stil liked your simple easy solution on the distortion :)

Answer (score 3):

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    0%{ transform:translateY(-90px);}
    50%{ transform:translateY(120px);}
    100%{ transform:translateY(-90px);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
 body{background: #92348A;
  font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
  
 .wrapper{ margin-left:370px;
   margin-top:195px;
   position:absolute;
   }
 p{ font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive;
  font-weight:900;
 
  }
 .one{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:0.5em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #F00;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.2s infinite ;
  } 
 .two{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #9D1A76;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.38s infinite;} 
 .three{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #FF0080;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.3s infinite;} 
 .four{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #FF0;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.35s infinite;} 
 .five{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #0ECAF1;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.23s infinite;} 
 .six{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #0BF451;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.1s infinite;}
 .seven{width:50px;
  height:50px;
  float:left;
  margin:1em;
  position:relative;
  border-radius:100%;
  background: #645CF1;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-animation:bounce 2s cubic-bezier(0.1,0.1,.3,1.9) 0.14s infinite;} 
  
 @-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    2%{ transform: translateY(120px);}
    50%{ transform:translateY(-90px);}
    100%{ transform:translateY(120px);}
    }
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="one">
         <p>W</p>
        </div>
        <div class="two">
         <p>E</p>
        </div>
        <div class="three">
         <p>L</p>
        </div>
        <div class="four">
         <p>C</p>
        </div>
        <div class="five">
         <p>O</p>
        </div>
        <div class="six">
         <p>M</p>
        </div>
         <div class="seven">
         <p>E</p>
        </div>
     </div>
</body>
```